# Error while generating a build in react native using @solana/web3.js

Tags: web3.js, react-native

I created a new react-native project using

```
npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript
```

Then I followed the steps metioned in the following url to install @solana/web3.js package
https://solanacookbook.com/integrations/react-native.html#create-a-new-app

Then I gave this command to generate the build

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

I am getting this error

```
error node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.native.js: Unexpected token name «n», expected punc «,» in file node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.native.js at 4276:32.
Error: Unexpected token name «n», expected punc «,» in file node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.native.js at 4276:32
    at minifyCode (/Users/username/Workspace/sampleproj/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:99:13)
    at transformJS (/Users/username/Workspace/sampleproj/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:317:28)
    at transformJSWithBabel (/Users/username/Workspace/sampleproj/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:408:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.transform (/Users/username/Workspace/sampleproj/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:569:12)
```

Can anyone help me out??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native build error when installing @solana/wallet-adapter "Module parse failed"](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2552/react-native-build-error-when-installing-solana-wallet-adapter-module-parse-fa)

Comment: The Cookbook that you followed has now been updated with new instructions that should solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

The `n` token that the bundle step is failing on is part of a JavaScript `bigint` literal. These are literals of the form `10000n`. At a certain point, `@solana/web3.js` began to admit code made up of bigint literals.

Your version of React Native does not support bigint literals. Check out the minimum requirements in the [README of `@solana/web3.js`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/web3.js/README.md#compatibility).