# React Native build error when installing @solana/wallet-adapter "Module parse failed"

Tags: react, walletadapter, js

I recently installed the @solana packages in order to use the Solana Wallet Adapter but am now running into build errors. The packages I installed using npm are

- @solana/wallet-adapter-base ^0.9.16
- @solana/wallet-adapter-react ^0.15.18
- @solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui ^0.9.16
- @solana/web3.js ^1.54.1
- @solana/wallet-adapter-wallets ^0.18.7

The build error I get is

```
./node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js 3673:30
Module parse failed: Identifier directly after number (3673:30)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     key: "isActive",
|     value: function isActive() {
>       var U64_MAX = Math.pow(2n, 64n) - 1n;
|       return this.state.deactivationSlot === U64_MAX;
|     }
```

I am currently running react ^18.1.0

Answer (score 4):

Two problems here:

1. Your compiler looks like it's using a transform that turns `2n ** 64n` into `Math.pow(2n, 64n)`. This is actually illegal because `Math.pow()` does not support `BigInt` – only `number`. An example of such a transform is `babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator`.
2. `BigInt` literal expressions (eg. `2n`) are only supported when your compiler targets ES2020. One solution is to upgrade your compiler's target, but another solution is to [file an issue](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/new/choose) against `@solana-labs/solana` asking for these literals to be rewritten as `BigInt(2)` and `BigInt(64)`.

Comment: This essentially smells like you're using React Native, in which case this additional context will be useful: https://twitter.com/steveluscher/status/1563940218444840960

Answer (score 4):

Your build problems stem from the fact that the version of React Native you're using runs code in a JavaScript environment that doesn't support `BigInt`, and `BigInt` is required by versions of `@solana/web3.js` from v1.41.7 and onward.

One solution is to install (or upgrade to) React Native 0.70 and switch to the Hermes JavaScript engine.

- More context on why, from the Solana Labs team: https://twitter.com/steveluscher/status/1565232091260157952
- Upgrade guide: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.69.5&to=0.70.0-rc.4
- Notes on Hermes as the new default engine in React Native >=0.70: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2022/07/08/hermes-as-the-default