# Unable to resolve superstruct

Tags: web3.js

I'm trying to install solana/web3.js but when i try to compile the project i'm facing this error:

```
Unable to resolve "superstruct" from "node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.native.js"
```

Env:

```
"react-native": "0.69.6",
"@solana/web3.js": "1.66.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Versions of `@solana/web3.js` from 1.41.7 onward require React Native 0.70. You can read more in this answer on a similar question: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/2688/75.